# ProcessMaker - Email not sent from web entry

Tags: processmaker

I have created a simple process, consisting of one task.  The task requires a Dynaform to be completed and a trigger is executed in the After Dynaform event to send an email to a group.

The process functions as intended when I create cases from within ProcessMaker.  The case is created and the email is sent.  When a case is created via web entry however, the trigger doesn't execute.  I have verified this from the logs.

I also tried using the End Event: Email Message but see the same behavior i.e. mail sent sent when starting case in PM but not sent when using web entry.

Would anyone be able to provide some insight an on why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using an old version of ProcessMaker by the fact that you are talking about Trigger and DynaForms.  Are you using Version 3?  If so, we recommend that you start looking at Version 4 (4.0.13 is the latest release) - https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker

thanks,

brian